# OL3: Clustering Vector Features when can't determine Feature type

Tags: openlayers-3

I have to load some Features in a Vector layer and have a style function.

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures( geojsonStr, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});         

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features,
}); 


/*
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 15,
    source: vectorSource
});
*/          

var customStyleFunction = function( feature, resolution ) {
   ....
}

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    //source: clusterSource,
    source: vectorSource,
    style : customStyleFunction
});

map.addLayer( vectorLayer );
```

I don't know what kind of geometry I will get in `geojsonStr`. The problem is: When my collection is of type "Point" I can cluster it, but with any other types I can't see the Layer... How can I cluster Points and ignore Polygons and Lines? or let OL3 be clever enough to decide?

**EDIT:** I've read https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/4917

Comment: So, you want to get all the features, and check them individually to add them to the vector source in case they are a Point, and ignore them completely if they are something else, right? Or do you want to do something else with the other features?

Comment: No. I have a GeoJSON string with a FeatureCollection. For now we can presume all geometries are the same type. The problem is I must set the source before I know what kind of geometries I have in the collection and can't determine if I can use the `clusterSource` or the `vectorSource` in my `vectorLayer`. But ....(not the main problem) would be great if I could receive a mixed FeatureCollection and cluster only Points leaving other geometries untouched.

Comment: After reading https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/4917 I'm almost there but still can't conditionally choose `vectorSource` or `clusterSource` to attach to `vectorLayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to create 2 different layers: One for clustering and a another one for a common vector layer.

To solve your problem, you can loop through the features and check the geometry type of each, and add it to an already existing source with the `addFeature` method:

```
for (var i = 0; i < geojsonFeatures.length; i++) {
    if (geojsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
        clusterSource.addFeature(geojsonFeatures[i]);
    } else {
        vectorSource.addFeature(geojsonFeatures[i]);
    }
}
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa2v645c/) which gets a couple of features from a GeoJSON object and add them to different sources depending on the geometry type. If you want to see more points in the cluster souce to make sure that it is working properly, you can use the commented lines as well.

Comment: You're a genius! Great solution! Worked like a charm.